# Preconfigure WiFi Networks in OS X Ventura

Tags: macos, wifi-configuration, osx-ventura

I'd like to preconfigure WiFi networks for the different offices I visit.  Did Ventura remove this ability?  Or maybe it's somewhere a bit more hidden than it used to be?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague. I assume you are referring to the order in which known wifi networks are joined when more than one is available.

If so, then apparently yes Apple removed this feature from the Ventura user interface. Unbelievably stupid decision on Apple's part – did Elon take over?

The immediate remedy is to turn off auto-join for the networks you don't want to consider (I'm surprised that Apple even saw fit to throw us that bone). Another remedy is to throw them all away and then re-add them in reverse priority but I think macOS in its infinite wisdom will then study your habits and adjust as it sees fit.

I've seen reference to a command line reconfiguration method but also references that it doesn't work as expected. I haven't investigated.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).